# Typeorm dynamic query builder from structured object

Tags: graphql, typeorm

For use in a graphql server I have defined a structured input type where you can specify a number of filter conditions very similar to how prisma works:

[image]

Which allows me to submit structured filters in a query like:

```js
{
  users(
    where: {
      OR: [{ email: { starts_with: "ja" } }, { email: { ends_with: ".com" } }],
      AND: [{ email: { starts_with: "ja" } }, { email: { ends_with: ".com" } }],
      email: {contains: "lowe"}
    }
  ) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

Inside my resolver I feed the args.where through a function to parse the structure and utilize TypeOrm's query builder to convert it to proper sql.  The entirety of the function is:

```js
import { Brackets } from "typeorm";

export const filterQuery = (query: any, where: any) => {
  if (!where) {
    return query;
  }

  Object.keys(where).forEach(key => {
    if (key === "OR") {
      where[key].map((queryArray: any) => {
        query.orWhere(new Brackets(qb => filterQuery(qb, queryArray)));
      });
    } else if (key === "AND") {
      where[key].map((queryArray: any) => {
        query.andWhere(new Brackets(qb => filterQuery(qb, queryArray)));
      });
    } else {
      const whereArgs = Object.entries(where);

      whereArgs.map(whereArg => {
        const [fieldName, filters] = whereArg;
        const ops = Object.entries(filters);

        ops.map(parameters => {
          const [operation, value] = parameters;

          switch (operation) {
            case "is": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} = :isvalue`, { isvalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "not": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} != :notvalue`, { notvalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "in": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} IN :invalue`, { invalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "not_in": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} NOT IN :notinvalue`, {
                notinvalue: value
              });
              break;
            }
            case "lt": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} < :ltvalue`, { ltvalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "lte": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} <= :ltevalue`, { ltevalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "gt": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} > :gtvalue`, { gtvalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "gte": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} >= :gtevalue`, { gtevalue: value });
              break;
            }
            case "contains": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} ILIKE :convalue`, {
                convalue: `%${value}%`
              });
              break;
            }
            case "not_contains": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} NOT ILIKE :notconvalue`, {
                notconvalue: `%${value}%`
              });
              break;
            }
            case "starts_with": {
              query
                .andWhere(`${fieldName} ILIKE :swvalue`)
                .setParameter("swvalue", `${value}%`);
              break;
            }
            case "not_starts_with": {
              query
                .andWhere(`${fieldName} NOT ILIKE :nswvalue`)
                .setParameter("nswvalue", `${value}%`);
              break;
            }
            case "ends_with": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} ILIKE :ewvalue`, {
                ewvalue: `%${value}`
              });
              break;
            }
            case "not_ends_with": {
              query.andWhere(`${fieldName} ILIKE :newvalue`, {
                newvalue: `%${value}`
              });
              break;
            }
            default: {
              break;
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });

  return query;
};
```

Which works (kinda) but does not nest the AND/OR queries like I would expect (and had previously got working in KNEX).  The above function generates the SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  "user"."id" AS "user_id",
  "user"."name" AS "user_name",
  "user"."email" AS "user_email",
  "user"."loginToken" AS "user_loginToken",
  "user"."loginTokenExpiry" AS "user_loginTokenExpiry",
  "user"."active" AS "user_active",
  "user"."visible" AS "user_visible",
  "user"."isStaff" AS "user_isStaff",
  "user"."isBilling" AS "user_isBilling",
  "user"."createdAt" AS "user_createdAt",
  "user"."updatedAt" AS "user_updatedAt",
  "user"."version" AS "user_version"
FROM "user" "user"
WHERE (email ILIKE $1)
  AND (email ILIKE $2)
  OR (email ILIKE $3)
  OR (email ILIKE $4)
  AND email ILIKE $5
-- PARAMETERS: ["ja%","%.com","ja%","%.com","%lowe%"]
```

But I would expect to see something more like:

```js
..... 
WHERE email ILIKE '%low%' 
AND (
    email ILIKE 'ja%' AND email ILIKE '%.com'
) AND (
    email ILIKE 'ja%' OR email ILIKE '%.com'
)
```

Forgive the nonsense, repetitive query. I'm just trying to illustrated the expected NESTED statements.

How can I force the AND/OR branches of my query builder function to properly nest like expected?

** Bonus points if someone can help me figure out the actual typescript typings here **

Comment: in your example query, there is { id email}, are you sure this is you are getting because it is seems to be a json, json should have <key,value> pair. Also what is query? you are calling query.orWhere

Comment: Thanks Shadab. It's not json, its a standard Graphql query. Id and email represent the return fields I want back from the query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Split it up into 2 functions to make adding the types easier
2. In your case statements you need to do orWhere or andWhere
3. Instead of mapping over the brackets, lift it up one level

```js
import { Brackets, WhereExpression, SelectQueryBuilder } from "typeorm";

interface FieldOptions {
  starts_with?: string;
  ends_with?: string;
  contains?: string;
}

interface Fields {
  email?: FieldOptions;
}

interface Where extends Fields {
  OR?: Fields[];
  AND?: Fields[];
}

const handleArgs = (
  query: WhereExpression,
  where: Where,
  andOr: "andWhere" | "orWhere"
) => {
  const whereArgs = Object.entries(where);

  whereArgs.map(whereArg => {
    const [fieldName, filters] = whereArg;
    const ops = Object.entries(filters);

    ops.map(parameters => {
      const [operation, value] = parameters;

      switch (operation) {
        case "is": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} = :isvalue`, { isvalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "not": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} != :notvalue`, { notvalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "in": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} IN :invalue`, { invalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "not_in": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} NOT IN :notinvalue`, {
            notinvalue: value
          });
          break;
        }
        case "lt": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} < :ltvalue`, { ltvalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "lte": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} <= :ltevalue`, { ltevalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "gt": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} > :gtvalue`, { gtvalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "gte": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} >= :gtevalue`, { gtevalue: value });
          break;
        }
        case "contains": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} ILIKE :convalue`, {
            convalue: `%${value}%`
          });
          break;
        }
        case "not_contains": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} NOT ILIKE :notconvalue`, {
            notconvalue: `%${value}%`
          });
          break;
        }
        case "starts_with": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} ILIKE :swvalue`, {
            swvalue: `${value}%`
          });
          break;
        }
        case "not_starts_with": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} NOT ILIKE :nswvalue`, {
            nswvalue: `${value}%`
          });
          break;
        }
        case "ends_with": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} ILIKE :ewvalue`, {
            ewvalue: `%${value}`
          });
          break;
        }
        case "not_ends_with": {
          query[andOr](`${fieldName} ILIKE :newvalue`, {
            newvalue: `%${value}`
          });
          break;
        }
        default: {
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  });

  return query;
};

export const filterQuery = <T>(query: SelectQueryBuilder<T>, where: Where) => {
  if (!where) {
    return query;
  }

  Object.keys(where).forEach(key => {
    if (key === "OR") {
      query.andWhere(
        new Brackets(qb =>
          where[key]!.map(queryArray => {
            handleArgs(qb, queryArray, "orWhere");
          })
        )
      );
    } else if (key === "AND") {
      query.andWhere(
        new Brackets(qb =>
          where[key]!.map(queryArray => {
            handleArgs(qb, queryArray, "andWhere");
          })
        )
      );
    }
  });

  return query;
};
```

Comment: This is FANTASTIC. Thank you Ben. The only case this does not cover is the root level statements not nested under AND or WHERE..  In the case of my example query above the `email: {contains: "lowe"}` is ignored.  In your opinion should I accept root level where statements or do should I require all statements to be nested in either OR or AND?
```

Comment: Now as I tinker more It starts to make more sense to only have AND/OR as the root level elements. It is far more explicit that way and not much of an inconvenience.

Comment: and if you did want to add it at the root level you can add an else where you call the function

`else {  handleArgs(query, where, "andWhere")  }`

Comment: This assumes no fields have a duplicate name, however, how might one address a case where two tables are joined and the function must distinguish between `id` in the first entity vs `id` in the second entity without getting error: `Error: ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`?

Comment: @benawad Sorry for that but are you [the ben awad](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-8QAzbLcRglXeN_MY9blyw)?

Comment: This opens code to SQL injections if used on user input.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Ben's answer, I tweaked a little the functions to allow a more versatile "*filter*" object:

```
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// enum
export enum Operator {
  AND = 'AND',
  OR = 'OR',
}

// interfaces
interface FieldOptions {
  is?: string;
  not?: string;
  in?: string;
  not_in?: string;
  lt?: string;
  lte?: string;
  gt?: string;
  gte?: string;
  contains?: string;
  not_contains?: string;
  starts_with?: string;
  not_starts_with?: string;
  ends_with?: string;
  not_ends_with?: string;
}

export interface Field {
  [key: string]: FieldOptions;
}

export type Where = {
  [K in Operator]?: (Where | Field)[];
};

// functions
export const filterQuery = <T>(query: SelectQueryBuilder<T>, where: Where) => {
  if (!where) {
    return query;
  } else {
    return traverseTree(query, where) as SelectQueryBuilder<T>;
  }
};

const traverseTree = (query: WhereExpression, where: Where, upperOperator = Operator.AND) => {
  Object.keys(where).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === Operator.OR) {
      query = query.orWhere(buildNewBrackets(where, Operator.OR));
    } else if (key === Operator.AND) {
      query = query.andWhere(buildNewBrackets(where, Operator.AND));
    } else {
      // Field
      query = handleArgs(query, where as Field, upperOperator === Operator.AND ? 'andWhere' : 'orWhere');
    }
  });

  return query;
};

const buildNewBrackets = (where: Where, operator: Operator) => {
  return new Brackets((qb) =>
    where[operator].map((queryArray) => {
      traverseTree(qb, queryArray, operator);
    }),
  );
};

const handleArgs = (query: WhereExpression, field: Field, andOr: 'andWhere' | 'orWhere') => {
  ...
};
```

This way we now can have this kind of object as a query parameter:

```
{
  AND: [
    {
      OR: [
        {
          name: {
            is: 'John'
          },
        },
        {
          surname: {
            is: 'Doe'
          },
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      AND: [
        {
          age: {
            gt: 30
          },
        },
        {
          type: {
            not: 'Employee'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      registered_date: {
        gte: '2000-01-01'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulting query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM users U 
WHERE (U.name = 'John' OR U.surname = 'Doe') AND (U.age > 30 AND U.type != 'Employee') AND U.registered_date >= '2000-01-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

When running expect:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users U 
WHERE (U.name = 'John' OR U.surname = 'Doe') OR (U.age > 30 AND U.type != 'Employee') AND U.registered_date >= '2000-01-01';
```

and not:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users U 
WHERE (U.name = 'John' OR U.surname = 'Doe') AND (U.age > 30 AND U.type != 'Employee') AND U.registered_date >= '2000-01-01';
```